# How To Reinitialize tinyMCE with fresh data after an AJAX Call?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a page which is used for both create and update. When a user writes a name and if that name doesn't exist in database it will be added along with the newly created description (through tinyMCE plugin) (This part works perfectly). But when user selects an already existing name, an AJAX request is fired to pull the description. I am able to pull the description correctly but the response (text) is not shown in the tinyMCE. I am using the latest version of tinyMCE.

My question is how can i reinitialize the tinyMCE control which has already been initialize on page load, or is there any other way to achieve this, as i want the existing description to be updated

Answer (score 2):

You don't need perform re-initialize editor, using below command `tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('some content here')` instead. Can you try this?